# Есть круговая диаграмма. Как обновить экран после нажатия кнопки, где изменяется значение одного её куска?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

```
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.echo.holographlibrary.PieGraph;
import com.echo.holographlibrary.PieSlice;

import static com.example.vdk.bablow_v2.R.id.graph;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int basket = 1, box = 1, car = 1, coctail = 1, knife = 1, home = 1, plane =         1, trash = 1;
Button button_plus;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    PieGraph pg = (PieGraph)findViewById(graph);
    PieSlice slice = new PieSlice();
    slice.setColor(Color.parseColor("#e74c3c"));
    slice.setValue(basket);
    pg.addSlice(slice);

    slice = new PieSlice();
    slice.setColor(Color.parseColor("#e67e22"));
    slice.setValue(box);
    pg.addSlice(slice);

    slice = new PieSlice();
    slice.setColor(Color.parseColor("#4D4D4D"));
    slice.setValue(car);
    pg.addSlice(slice);

    slice = new PieSlice();
    slice.setColor(Color.parseColor("#34495e"));
    slice.setValue(coctail);
    pg.addSlice(slice);

    slice = new PieSlice();
    slice.setColor(Color.parseColor("#9b59b6"));
    slice.setValue(knife);
    pg.addSlice(slice);

    slice = new PieSlice();
    slice.setColor(Color.parseColor("#3498db"));
    slice.setValue(home);
    pg.addSlice(slice);

    slice = new PieSlice();
    slice.setColor(Color.parseColor("#27ae60"));
    slice.setValue(plane);
    pg.addSlice(slice);

    slice = new PieSlice();
    slice.setColor(Color.parseColor("#16a085"));
    slice.setValue(trash);
    pg.addSlice(slice);

    button_plus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_plus);
}

public void ClickButtonPlus(View view) {
    basket = 12;
}

}
```

`PieGraph` - виджет из библиотеки [HoloGraphLibrary](https://github.com/Androguide/HoloGraphLibrary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант 1. Послать в ваш `PieGraph pg` команду `pg.removeSlices()` и затем добавить заново слайсы с новыми значениями.

Вариант 2. Сохранить ссылки на добавленные в `pg` слайсы. После нажатия на кнопку у соответствующего слайса изменить значение, выполнить `pg.update()`